# MacOSのSwift2でCoreDataを利用してPostgreSQLを操作したい。

Tags: macos, swift2

MacOS上のSwift2を利用してCoreDataを使いPostgreSQLのデータを操作する方法を知りたいです。
CoreDataはSQLiteに対応しているようですが、この部分をPostgreSQLに置き換える(または、書換える)にはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

CoreDataを利用してRDBMSを操作できるようにしたいと考えています。

わかる方がいらっしゃれば、ご指導よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

CoreDataは汎用のORMライブラリではありませんので、バックエンドのDBを切り替えるといったことは基本的にはできません。
CoreDataのバックエンドとして利用可能なものはXML、バイナリ形式、SQLiteそしてインメモリ、の４種類です。（iOSではXMLは利用不可）

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html